# Restore my compressed and encrypted archive file in mysql/mariaDB with prompt windows

Tags: mysql, openssl, gzip

In an internet guide i found [link](https://severalnines.com/blog/how-encrypt-your-mysql-mariadb-backups):
Encrypt backup on the fly

```
mysqldump -u root -ppassword myDatabase | gzip | openssl  enc -aes-256-cbc -k PASSWORD > BACKUP.ENC
```

mysqldump ... etc work! I get the backup file compressed and encrypted.

For restore, i wrote this, but it doesn't work:

```
 openssl  -aes-256-cbc -d -k PASSWORD -in backup.xb.enc -out | gzip -d < | mysql -u user -pPASSWORD myDatabase
```

How can I restore my database correctly?

My version is: 10.1.31-MariaDB

I solved this:

```
openssl  enc -aes-256-cbc -d  -in BACKUP.sql.gz.ENC  -k PASSWORD  | gzip  -d | mysql  -u root -pPASSWORD myDatabase
```

Thanks for collaboration.

Comment: the article says `openssl aes-256-cbc -d -in backup_file.tar.gz.enc -out backup_file.tar.gz -k yoursecretpassword` seams you are missing the filename with the `-out` param?

Comment: -out should be managed by gzip
and the decompressed result
managed by mysql

Comment: Maybe take a look into [mysqldump-secure](https://mysqldump-secure.org/) instead?

Comment: thanks, if I can't, I'll try mysqldump-secure.

Comment: I solved this:
    openssl  enc -aes-256-cbc -d  -in BACKUP.ENC  -k PASSWORD  | gzip  -d | mysql  -u root -pPASSWORD myDatabase

Thanks for collaboration.